# Issue installing geopandas package

Tags: python, pip, geopandas, gdal, fiona

I understand that GDAL is a prerequisite and have followed other threads to download the wheel file from [Laboratory of Fluorescence Dynamics](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) even taking note which file to download based on the python version for compatibility however, there is still an error

If I were to run "python -m pip install GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64"

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64

If I were to run "python -m pip install "C:\Users\foo\bar...\GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64"

> ERROR: GDAL-3.4.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Hope anyone out there can enlighten me with this issue.

Comment: can you use conda? that's the [recommended installation method](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html#installing-with-anaconda-conda) and it works much, much more smoothly

Comment: I think you need to add the `.whl` extension